# How to count the number of different elements in a 3D tensor (or array) fast?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, count

Input a 3D tensor (or numpy array), say size ([2, 2, 3])

```
T = torch.tensor([[[1,1,1],[1,2,1]],[[2,2,2],[1,4,5]]])

tensor([[[1, 1, 1],
         [1, 2, 1]],
        [[2, 2, 2],
         [1, 4, 5]]])
```

I want to count the number of different elements in each row and expect return:

```
tensor([[[1],
         [2]],
        [[1],
         [3]]])
```

I am now using

```
color_count = torch.zeros((T.shape[0], T.shape[1], 1),dtype = int)
for i in range(T.shape[0]):
    for j in range(T.shape[1]):
        count = len(T[i][j,:].unique())
        color_count[i][j][0] = count
```

But it's too slow as I have to do it many times. Anyone could help to improve the speed please.

Comment: Would a numpy solution be of interest?

Comment: Yes, I can convert them to an array and actually a lot of usage is the same for both. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Dani, could you still help? Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `numpy` solution suits you, `numpy` has a faster alternative to loops: [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)

```py
# assuming `T` is a 3d numpy array: 
np.apply_along_axis(lambda row: [len(np.unique(row))], axis=2, arr=T)
```

Also note that `set(row)` may work faster than `np.unique(row)` for small arrays.